# Examples in Doctor Who of the Doctor acquiring or losing abilities with different regenerations?

Tags: doctor-who, regeneration, martial-arts

I remember Jon Pertwee's third Doctor was portrayed as a martial arts expert - a skill I don't remember any other Doctor displaying.

Are there other examples of skills or abilities that seem to have come and gone from regeneration to regeneration?

Answer (score 10):

Save for the most recent regeneration, there's no evidence that any skills are "lost" as much as the new regeneration chooses to use other skills.

There's been several examples of things being "deleted" in Capaldi's regeneration, mostly played for whimsy.  This started in his audition, where Moffat wrote some lines for him to read, a scene set shortly after his regeneration where he comments that he'd lost the ability to hop, and to speak French.

> THE DOCTOR: Right then, eyesight. Not bad, bit blue. Ears – not
>   pointy, right way up, more or less level. Face – well I’ve got one.
>   Oh, no – French!
>
> CLARA: French.
>
> THE DOCTOR: I’ve deleted French! Plus all cookery skills, and the
>   breast stroke. And hopping. Never mind hopping, who needs to hop. Ohh,
>   the kidneys are interesting. Never had that before – interesting
>   kidneys.

([source](http://www.denofgeek.com/tv/doctor-who/26586/doctor-who-steven-moffats-12th-doctor-audition-script))

In Under the Lake, The Doctor realizes he'd lost/deleted the ability to use sign language.

Comment: Ah okay, that's interesting (have to admit I haven't seen much of Capaldi's Doctor, as much as I like the actor).

Comment: I agree. I can think of a few skills that one particular doctor used that no other doctor's did, but there's zero evidence that the skill was actually lost.

E.g Troughton playing the flute, Tom Baker the expert swordsman (Androids of Tara) and Davison the all round cricketer (Black Orchid).

Comment: @Moriarty Good points. The thing that made me think particularly about Pertwee's Doctor's martial arts prowess was that there were a few situations faced by subsequent Doctors where those skills could have come in handy if he'd still possessed them!

Comment: @Moriarty and Matt Smith's mad soccer skills!!

Comment: Oh, does this count? Three was a wine lover. In fact, he was quite the connoisseur. But Eleven didn't know what wine tasted like - he was disappointed that it didn't taste like winegums.

Comment: Maybe by 'deleted French' he meant not saying "Allons-y" at every opportunity.